# MYSQL query optimization for SQL query with IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have below SQL query which i am constructing dynamically based on user input . While the query performs reasonably well as long as IN parameters are < 50 .However as soon as IN list grows query response time degrades significantly.

I have tried splitting query in multiple queries with small input and firing all queries in parallel .This definitely gives me better performance

However i would like to avoid splitting query , would like to know if any other (better) way i can optimize this query further ( i am thinking if by someway i can use join by creating temp tables )

[pls note col1 & col2 are already an index ]

```
SELECT a.col3, b.col5, b.col4, ...
FROM A a 
  JOIN B b ON a.apk = b.afk AND a.bfk = b.bpk  
WHERE a.col1 IN (1, 2, 3, ...)  
  AND a.col2 IN ('abc', 'pqr', ...) 
  AND a.flag = 1
```

Comment: Create a temp table out of those params and JOIN on it

Comment: ON a.apk = b.afk AND a.bfk = b.bpk....is it right as you joining both tables based on 2 different columns...

Comment: As a minimum, questions about query performance ALWAYS require proper CREATE statements for all relevant tables AND the result of the EXPLAIN.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does a good job of handling `IN` queries with constants.  Unlike many other databases, it actually sorts the inputs and uses a binary tree for the searching.  So, my guess is that the volume of data is the issue rather than the `IN` itself.  The fact that parallel threads work better just speaks to the fact that MySQL doesn't use all available resources for an individual query.

You can try indexes.  For this query:

```
SELECT a.col3, b.col5, b.col4, ...
FROM A a JOIN
     B b
     ON a.apk = b.afk AND a.bfk = b.bpk  
WHERE a.col1 IN (1, 2, 3, ...) AND
      a.col2 IN ('abc', 'pqr', ...) AND
      a.flag = 1 ;
```

You want indexes on `b(fk, bpk)` and either `a(flag, col1, col2)` or `a(flag, col2, col1)`.  The multi-column index can help with the `IN`, but only for one of them, so the more selective should be the second column in the index.